# Browser cache conflicts with my javascript to add values to list box

Tags: javascript, sql-server, caching, asp-classic, listbox

I've made a javascript to make a list of values for a list box. The values comes from database in `SQL Server`. when I make some change with the values on database, the values on my list box don't update. It seems that the browser caches the value or something, because when I clear the cache on my browser, the values in the list box update.

here is my javascript (authapp.js):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).load(function(){                           
    var loads = '<table>'+
                '<tr>'+
                '<td align="center" class="label">'+
                '<img src="../../../Images/loading.gif" alt="Please wait..."
                  align="middle" style="width:30px;height:30px;">'+
                '</td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '<tr>'+
                '<td align="center" class="label">'+
                '<font color="#FFFFFF" face="Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif">Loading...</font>'+
                '</td>'+
                '</tr>'+
                '</table>';

    //load selected customer
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "master/authtpl/queries/get_sel_cust.asp",
        data: "cunit="+$('#cunit').val()+"&ccduser="+$('#ccduser').val(),
        beforeSend: function(){
                $('#load_sel').block({ 
                message: loads, 
                css: { border: 'none',
                       top: '10%',
                       width: '10%',
                       backgroundColor: '#606060', 
                       opacity: '0.3'
                      } 
                });
             },
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response) {
          $('#load_sel').unblock();
          if(response==undefined){
              alert('List q of Selected Customer is not available!');
          } else {
              $('#selSelected').empty();
              var cust = (typeof response.cust) == 'string' ? eval('(' + response.cust + ')') : response.cust;
              // get data from json
              var count = 0,strs = '';
              lent = cust.length;
                do {
                  strs += '<option value="'+cust[count].ckode+'|'+cust[count].cgrup+'|'+cust[count].cnama+'">'+cust[count].ckode+' - '+cust[count].cnama;
                  count++;
                } while (count < lent);
                $('#selSelected').append(strs);
          }
        }
      });   
    });
});
```

and here is my query to get that value (get_sel_cust.asp):

```
<!-- #INCLUDE file = "../../../include/createconnection.asp" -->

<%
    dwdb = Application("DWDB")


    ccdappl = Application("CCDAPPL")
    ckdunitkey = trim(Request.QueryString("cunit"))
    ccduser = trim(Request.QueryString("ccduser"))

    sql = "select distinct ckdrelasi,ckdgruprelasi,vnamarelasi  "&_
          "from " & dwdb & ".dwaustasia.dbo.ms_webuser_apprtpl "&_
          "where ckdunitkey='"&ckdunitkey&"' and ccduser='"&ccduser&"' and ccdappl='"&ccdappl&"' "&_
          "order by ckdrelasi"
    objCommand.commandText = sql
    'response.write sql
    set aloc = objCommand.execute
    if NOT aloc.BOF then
        aloc.moveFirst
        json = "{ ""cust"" : [ "
        body_json = ""
        temp = ""
        WHILE NOT aloc.EOF
            temp =  "{"&_
                            """ckode"":"""&aloc("ckdrelasi")&""","&_
                            """cgrup"":"""&aloc("ckdgruprelasi")&""","&_                            
                            """cnama"":"""&aloc("vnamarelasi")&""""&_
                    "},"
            body_json = body_json&temp
            aloc.moveNext
        WEND
        body_json = mid(body_json,1,len(body_json)-1)
        json2 = "   ] } "   
        hasil = json&body_json&json2
        response.write hasil
    end if  

    set objCommand = nothing
    response.end
%>
```

and this is the list box form (default.asp):

```
<SELECT name="selSelected" id="selSelected" MULTIPLE SIZE="10" class="label" style="width:250px;">

                    </SELECT>
```

I don't know where is the problem comes from. Can you tell me did I make some mistake on my coding? thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling the AJAX caching in jQuery:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
    // Disable caching of AJAX responses
    cache: false
});
```

There are loads of places caching can happen - but it'll be easier to start with the client and work backwards.

Comment: well, it works! thanks @web_bod :)
this program made by previous programmer, and he didn't give any documentation on his coding, so it's hard for me to tracking this code. btw, thanks for your advice too :)

Comment: no worries - I work freelance have learned it's always best to blame the client first :p